# Barplot in R with stacked columns and custom x axis labels

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am new to R and I have the following database structure:

```
names <- c("a","b","c","d")
val1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
val2 <- c(2,3,4,5)
df <- cbind(val1,val2)
rownames(df) <- names
df
```

I want to barplot the two value columns (stacking the columns next to each other) and have the rownames of the dataframe as x labels.

The excel plot would look like this:

[image]
Any hint on how to achieve this?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the bars next to each other is a "dodged" bar plot, not a "stacked" bar plot, which implies the bars are positioned on top of each other. In base R you could do:

```r
barplot(t(df), beside = TRUE, col = c("#4f81bd", "#c0504d"))
```

[image]

This is a *dodged* bar plot.

If you want a stacked bar plot, it would be:

```r
barplot(t(df), beside = FALSE, col = c("#4f81bd", "#c0504d"))
```

[image]
If you want full customization of all the graphical elements, using `ggplot` is a better approach. For example, if you really love that MS Excel look:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(rowname, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4f81bd", "#c0504d"), 
                    labels = c('Series1', 'Series2'), name = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:6, limits = c(0, 6), name = NULL) +
  labs(x = NULL, title = 'Chart title') +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: He wants them stacked... as in the base R parameter to barplot() beside=FALSE. Forget the ggplot equivalent at the moment. But it's there. Ah yes...here:  ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")

Comment: @JohnGarland I don't think he wants them stacked. He says he wants them stacked, but he seems to think this means having the bars "next to each other", so I think he means dodged. Also, `geom_bar(position = 'identity')` is just a long way of writing `geom_col()`, and is a bit outdated.

Comment: Yeah...you have a point, I think. I saw the word 'stacked' and took the other meaning.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion about the word stacked, I actually intended dodged... Can I just ask how can I set to zero the distance between bars in each group?

Comment: In ggplot you would do `geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), width = 0.5)`. In base R barplot, there is already no space between them.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, using base R you need to make a matrix and transpose for it to work right...

```
 names <- c("a","b","c","d")
 val1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
 val2 <- c(2,3,4,5)
 df <- cbind(val1,val2)
 rownames(df) <- names
 barplot(t(as.matrix(df)), beside=TRUE)
```

I was wrong above: t() works fine with dfs, so no as.matrix needed.

Comment: Ha! Just added this example as you were posting!